# Maven deploy-file goal: Why does the first execution interfere with the second one?

Tags: java, maven

If I call two deploy-file executions in the maven-deploy-plugin

```
<plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>

        <execution>
          <id>deploy-ejb-impl</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>deploy-file</goal>
          </goals>
          <phase>deploy</phase>
          <configuration>
            <file>${implJarFile}</file>
            <pomFile>${implPomFile}</pomFile>
            <url>${project.distributionManagementArtifactRepository.url}</url>
            <repositoryId>${project.distributionManagementArtifactRepository.id}</repositoryId>
            <javadoc>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-hund.jar</javadoc>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>default-deploy</id>
          <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>deploy-ejb-client</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>deploy-file</goal>
          </goals>
          <phase>deploy</phase>
          <configuration>
            <file>${clientJarFile}</file>
            <pomFile>${clientPomFile}</pomFile>
            <url>${project.distributionManagementArtifactRepository.url}</url>
            <repositoryId>${project.distributionManagementArtifactRepository.id}</repositoryId>
            <sources>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-hund.jar</sources>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
```

Then the upload of the javadoc from the first execution is also executed in the second execution (look for basis-vs-bo-20.0.2-20161103.130940-25-javadoc.jar):

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy-file (deploy-ejb-impl) @ basis-vs-bo ---
[INFO] Downloading: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1001 B at 15.5 KB/sec)
[INFO] Uploading: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/basis-vs-bo-20.0.2-20161103.130940-25.jar
[INFO] Uploaded: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/basis-vs-bo-20.0.2-20161103.130940-25.jar (160 KB at 3386.2 KB/sec)
[INFO] Uploading: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/basis-vs-bo-20.0.2-20161103.130940-25.pom
[INFO] Uploaded: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/basis-vs-bo-20.0.2-20161103.130940-25.pom (5 KB at 282.4 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo/maven-metadata.xml (372 B at 11.7 KB/sec)
[INFO] Uploading: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Uploaded: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1001 B at 65.2 KB/sec)
[INFO] Uploading: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Uploaded: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo/maven-metadata.xml (372 B at 24.2 KB/sec)
[INFO] Uploading: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/basis-vs-bo-20.0.2-20161103.130940-25-javadoc.jar
[INFO] Uploaded: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/basis-vs-bo-20.0.2-20161103.130940-25-javadoc.jar (77 KB at 5117.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] Uploading: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Uploaded: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 74.3 KB/sec)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy-file (deploy-ejb-client) @ basis-vs-bo ---
[INFO] Downloading: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo-client/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo-client/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1008 B at 30.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] Uploading: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo-client/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/basis-vs-bo-client-20.0.2-20161103.130941-14.jar
[INFO] Uploaded: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo-client/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/basis-vs-bo-client-20.0.2-20161103.130941-14.jar (24 KB at 1451.9 KB/sec)
[INFO] Uploading: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo-client/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/basis-vs-bo-client-20.0.2-20161103.130941-14.pom
[INFO] Uploaded: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo-client/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/basis-vs-bo-client-20.0.2-20161103.130941-14.pom (4 KB at 201.1 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo-client/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo-client/maven-metadata.xml (379 B at 11.9 KB/sec)
[INFO] Uploading: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo-client/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Uploaded: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo-client/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1008 B at 65.6 KB/sec)
[INFO] Uploading: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo-client/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Uploaded: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo-client/maven-metadata.xml (379 B at 24.7 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 37.1 KB/sec)
[INFO] Uploading: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/basis-vs-bo-20.0.2-20161103.130940-25-javadoc.jar
[INFO] Uploaded: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/basis-vs-bo-20.0.2-20161103.130940-25-javadoc.jar (77 KB at 5117.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo/maven-metadata.xml (372 B at 11.7 KB/sec)
[INFO] Uploading: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Uploaded: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 79.2 KB/sec)
[INFO] Uploading: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Uploaded: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo/maven-metadata.xml (372 B at 24.2 KB/sec)
[INFO] Uploading: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo-client/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/basis-vs-bo-client-20.0.2-20161103.130941-14-sources.jar
[INFO] Uploaded: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo-client/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/basis-vs-bo-client-20.0.2-20161103.130941-14-sources.jar (77 KB at 4797.9 KB/sec)
[INFO] Uploading: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo-client/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Uploaded: http://ik-repo1:8084/nexus/content/repositories/consnapshots/de/continentale/vs/basis-vs-bo-client/20.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1008 B at 61.5 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Why does the parameter javadoc cause the second execution to upload the same file again?

Comment: Aaah that is starting to look like a bug that is present in the `deploy-file` goal which is fixed in the current snapshot. Look at [MDEPLOY-212](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEPLOY-212) and [MDEPLOY-213](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEPLOY-213). Can you try with the latest 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT? You can build it from source [here](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins/tree/trunk/maven-deploy-plugin) or add [Apache snapshot repo](http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/).

Comment: Basically, it currently messes up a bit with the current Maven project if it's inside one, by adding attached artifacts to it, which would explain why it's deployed twice

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. Your level of expertise is really amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tunaki said in the comment, version 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT of the deploy plugin corrects the error.